# INode File System, what is the extra space in a data block used for?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, storage

So, I am currently learning about the INode file system and am asked to write a simple file system using Inodes.

So far, I understand that there is an INode table that has a mapping from INode-> Data blocks through direct/indirect pointers.

Let's assume data gets written into a file, the data is stored into two blocks. Let's say each block is 512bytes, and the file takes one full block, and only 200 bytes of the second block. What happens with the rest of the space in that data block? Is it reserved for that file only or do other files use this block?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file system, usually and most likely this area is now lost.  I think the [Reiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS) File System actually reclaimed this area, but I could be wrong.

Creating your own File System can be a challenging experience, but also an enjoyable experience.  I have created a few myself and worked on another.  If you are creating your own file system, you can have it do whatever you wish.

Look at the bottom of [this page](http://www.fysnet.net/ultimate/index.htm) for a few that I am working on/with.  The LeanFS in particular, uses Inodes as well.  The SFS is a very simple file system.  Each is well documented so that you can research and decide what you would like to do.

Comment: it's not lost, just unusable.